# if e else entre usurario

Tags: django, django-templates, django-2.0, django-admin

Assim, criei um tabela usuario e uma negocio, ambas herdam da tabela user do django.
Perfeito, ambas estão seus usuarios e tabelas.
Porem tenho um menu e uma página perfil.html
e queria que nesse menu aparecesse a foto e nome de quem estivar logando e o mesmo na página perfil
mais como tenho user.usuario e user.negocio
não sei como fazer essa lógica se estiver logado com user.usuario mostrar tal coisa senão mostrar user.negocio
alguém quer perder um tempo e me ajuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi muito bem sua pergunta mas vamos lá.

Pelo que entendi, você tem as duas classes (Usuario e Negocio) que herdam de User e quer verificar no template se o usuário que está logado pertence à classe Usuario ou Negocio.

Nessa situação, seria algo do tipo:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if request.user.usuario %}
        <img src="{{request.user.usuario.foto.url}}">
    {% elif request.user.negocio %}
        <img src="{{request.user.negocio.foto.url}}">
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Aqui, estou supondo que tanto Usuario quanto Negocio possuem um campo foto do tipo ImageField.

Porém essa não é a melhor forma de fazer algo assim no Django. O ideal seria você ter 2 grupos (usando o django.contrib.auth.models.Group) e vincular cada usuário a um dos grupos de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Se você quiser, coloca o projeto no Github e manda o link que te ajudo mais.

Abraço!

Comment: oi amigo excelente lócgica, mais apareceu o seguinte erro `Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: User has no usuario.` Uso o accounts do django admin para login

Comment: cara acho que deu certo, a noite te confirmo, mas se deu salvou minha vida

Comment: opa amigo, tentei e não deu certo, ele mostra a empresa, mais dai quando logo no usuario ele não mostra, e caso dentro do if do user.usuario eu peça a foto da user.negocio.foto ele aceita

Comment: Olá Mauricio. Você consegue me enviar o seu código pra eu dar uma olhada? Principalmente do models.py, views.py e o html que está tentando fazer?

Comment: https://github.com/MauMaster/Pet-Aqui    claro, só que lá dentro o menu nao ta com esse if, else elif

Comment: Agradeço qualquer ajuda, faz parte do meu TCC to desesperado

Comment: até publiquei outro post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369788/desdenti%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-dois-tipos-de-usu%C3%A1rios-usando-if/369799#369799

Comment: Mauricio. Estava preparando a resposta quando fechou o tópico. hehe

Comment: já reabri, por que não consegui ainda, agradeço se me ajudar amigo

Comment: Vi a outra pergunta lá. A resposta do Allan está bem completa. Mas, eu criei um novo models.py que acredito que deixaria seu banco de dados mais otimizado. Dá uma olhada e vê se te interessa: https://pastebin.com/0De0Sk0u

Comment: Outra coisa. Como eu disse, não é a forma mais correta de fazer isso mas, para um momento de desespero, funciona bem. hehe Qualquer coisa, estamos aí.

Comment: olha até onde fui, se puder me ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/370822/if-else-entre-dois-tipos-de-usuario