# Desdentição entre dois tipos de usuários usando if

Tags: django, django-2.0, django-admin

Opa, to usando o djando admin para login, pelo accounts, e estou usando o User extendido para duas tabelas diferentes, Negocio e Usuario, e estou fazendo cadastros totalmente deparados para user.negocio e user.usuario.
Até ai tudo bem, porém quando vou logar no sistema tenho um menu que uso via Inlcude e nele aparecem alguns dados do usuarios, nome, foto e mais alguns.
No código abaixo mostro como tentei a lógica de for user.negocio mostrar dados do usuario respectivo se for user.usuario o mesmo.
Mas o que notei é que o {% if user.is_authenticated %}  está validando e só ele, pois se dentro se coloco no primeiro if user.usuario.nome e user.negocio.nome e logo com usuario, ele mostra o nome, mesmo estando dentro do if do user.negocio
E não estou usando nenhuma views para o menu.html
E se eu tirar o elif e deixar mostrando no menu ambos nomes e fotos, quando logo com usuario aparecem os dados deles e quando logo com o negocio tbm, acho que o problema está no elif

menu.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %} 
   {% if user.negocio %}
     {{user.negocio.empresa}} 
     <img src="{{ user.negocio.foto.thumbnail.url}}">
{% elif user.usuario %}
     {{user.usuario.nome}}
     <img src="{{ user.usuario.foto.thumbnail.url}}" >
{% endif %} 
   {% else %}
       <form class="form-inline">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{% url 'login' %}"> Entrar </a>
       </div>
       </form>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi direito sua pergunta. Não sei se um User tem necessariamente tanto Usuario quanto Negocio ou se ele pode ou não ser um Negocio. Pois difere nesses casos.

Se um User só pode ser ou `Usuario` ou `Negocio`, você deve setar um deles como nulo. Dessa maneira você consegue fazer o if

```py
{% if user.negocio %}
     {{user.negocio.empresa}} 
     <img src="{{ user.negocio.foto.thumbnail.url}}">
{% elif user.usuario %}
     {{user.usuario.nome}}
     <img src="{{ user.usuario.foto.thumbnail.url}}" >
{% endif %}
```

Se um User pode ser tanto Usuario quanto Negócio, você deve controlar por meio do context por exemplo, em que modo você está por exemplo

```py
{% if modo_negocio %}
     {{user.negocio.empresa}} 
     <img src="{{ user.negocio.foto.thumbnail.url}}">
{% else %}
     {{user.usuario.nome}}
     <img src="{{ user.usuario.foto.thumbnail.url}}" >
{% endif %}
```

Pelo que entendi, o user pode conter Usuario e Negocio no seu código. Se você não colocasse `elif`, ele iria entrar nos dois `ifs` como você notou e iria mostrar as duas fotos (pois nenhum deles é nulo)

Comment: Olá amigo, sim user pode ser tanto usuario, quanto negocio, estou no trabalho agora, mas meio dia vou tentar esse seu codigo,  o ultimo que mandou, sou muito novato, como faço uso do context?

Comment: e você tem razão tanto Usuario quanto Negocio herdam de User, e os dois são tabelas deferentes
quero usar tanto no menu, se o user.usuario logar aparecer os dados, como se logar user.negocio os dados deles no menu
e  támbem quero usar esse sistema na parte de perfil meusite.com.br/perfil mostra user.usuario ou user.negocio tudo dentro de um perfil.html só

Comment: Context são como se fossem variáveis que são passadas da view para o template, um dicionário em Python. Você teria que passar na view ou pode criar um context processor para ser passado em todas as views. Suponho que comece pelo primeiro para entender o fluxo

Comment: Vou tentar montar esse context na minha view, como é passada para menu.html e esse é include dentro de todas as páginas, acredito que fazendo só para ele serveria né

Comment: Dá para utilizar session também

Comment: e como passar essas duas opções de view pele context?